# Instagram api response with empty data array in asp.net

Tags: instagram-api

I’m trying to access to Media use hashtag from the Instagram API using their authenticated access token.returns empty data.  I’m using this URL:  **https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{tag name}?access_token={verified access token}** and this is the result I’m receiving:  {"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []} Because it has a 200 return code, the access token is valid. So why don’t I see any liked posts?
i added another user in sandbox users but so returns empty data.
What to do? please help me!

[my C# code]

```
 static string code = string.Empty;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["code"]) && !Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            code = Request["code"];
            GetDataInstagramToken();
        }
    }
    public void GetDataInstagramToken()
    {
        var json = "";
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
            parameters.Add("client_id", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_id"]);
            parameters.Add("client_secret", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_secret"]);
            parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            parameters.Add("redirect_uri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirect_uri"]);
            parameters.Add("code", code);
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", parameters);
            var response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
            var jsResult = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            string accessToken = (string)jsResult["access_token"];
            Int64 id = Convert.ToInt64(jsResult["user"]["id"]);
            var clientid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_id"];
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GetToken", "<script>var ClientId=\"" + @"" + clientid + "" + "\";var instagramaccessid=\"" + @"" + id + "" + "\"; var instagramaccesstoken=\"" + @"" + accessToken + "" + "\";</script>");

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

my js code
 
  function GetSearchMedia() {

```
        var seachText = document.getElementById('Search').value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            async: true,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + seachText + '/media/recent?access_token=' + instagramaccesstoken,

            dataType: "jsonp",

            cache: false,

            beforeSend: function () {

                $("#loading").show();

            },

            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                for (var i = 0; i < data["data"].length; i++) {

                    $("#ImageUL").append("<li><img src=" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url + "></li>");

                }
            }

        });
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only see your and your sandbox users post in API response if they have posted a photo with the hashtag your are looking up using API.

So if you add a photo to instagram with an hashtag and then make API call for that hashtag, you will then see your post in API response <- try this

Comment: I see,Thank a lot for your explanation